# Error in multiple .ready() functions binding

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with some parts of it loaded with jQuery. Many of those parts have javascript code similar to:

```
console.log( "script X loaded"); 
$(document).ready( function() {
    console.log( "script X executed");
    // ... some code ...
});
```

The issue is that all of those functions where executed until I have updated to jQuery 1.7.1

Now in al least one of them the function is not excuted as it is in others, In console I can read:

```
script A loaded
script A executed
script B executed
```

And it ends without executing script B. I have tried to test it erasing all code inside the function in script B.

Do you have any clue about what may be happening?

Thank you!

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing details such as how you are loading the parts that are not properly executed.

Comment: not getting your question. please be clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to me like a race condition in which you are loading the required components in an inappropriate order, resulting in some of your code never becoming *ready* -- thus, never executing.

I might be entirely wrong, but that's usually the case for me.

Also, if the listener is attached to `document`, it might be that you have opened the document for writing at some point, and never closed it.

Comment: That was. I had to try erasing code in script A. It was a weird error but this execution didn't ended so function in script B was never called. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. This had happened to me before. It is a little unclear, sometimes, to think in terms of runnables (threads) that might lag due to network conditions.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you add

```
try{ ... }catch(error){console.log("error in method X " + error)}
```

wrapping you functions. This way you can know which error occurs on which method. 
I assume some exceptions is thrown which stops the execution.

I also suggest you work with chrome, click ctrl+shift+j to see the console, add "debugger;" in the code
like this

```
try{

    console.log("running method X");
    .... 
}catch(error){ debugger; console.log("error in method X : " + error); }
```

This will enable you to debug the code  when an error occurs.